# How to disable the "kube_audit" and "kube_audit_admin" AKS log settings via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

## Summary:

Using Terraform the goal is to disable the "kube_audit" and "kube_audit_admin" log settings from an Azure diagnostic setting. However, my solution seems to both enable and disable these settings at the same time. I am looking for the correct way to disable these settings via Terraform.

## My Solution

In Terraform I defined the following diagnostic setting for an AKS cluster:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "aks" {
  name                       = var.diag_name
  target_resource_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_workspace.id

  dynamic "log" {
    for_each = local.diag_agw_logs
    content {
      category = log.value

      retention_policy {
        days    = var.cluster_log_metrics_retention_in_days
        enabled = var.cluster_monitor_event_retention
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "metric" {
    for_each = local.diag_agw_metrics
    content {
      category = metric.value

      retention_policy {
        days    = var.cluster_log_metrics_retention_in_days
        enabled = var.cluster_monitor_event_retention
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The resource JSON looks like this (which is expected behaviour):

```
>> az monitor diagnostic-settings list --resource $(az aks list --query '[?contains(@.name, `mycluster`)].id | [0]' | tr -d '"')
[
  {
    "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": null,
    "eventHubName": null,
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/myresourcegroup/providers/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters/mycluster/providers/microsoft.insights/diagnosticSettings/mydiagnosticsetting",
    "identity": null,
    "kind": null,
    "location": null,
    "logAnalyticsDestinationType": null,
    "logs": [
      {
        "category": "cluster-autoscaler",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-scheduler",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-audit",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-audit-admin",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-controller-manager",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "guard",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-apiserver",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "marketplacePartnerId": null,
    "metrics": [
      {
        "category": "AllMetrics",
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        },
        "timeGrain": null
      }
    ],
    "name": "mydiagnosticsetting",
    "resourceGroup": "myresourcegroup",
    "serviceBusRuleId": null,
    "storageAccountId": null,
    "systemData": null,
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
    "workspaceId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/myloganalyticsworkspace"
  }
]
```

My goal is to disable the "kube_audit" and "kube_audit_admin" log settings. However, when I add log blocks to disable these audit logs in Terraform, after applying my changes the resource JSON looks unexpected. This is the new resource definition in Terraform (I only added the two log blocks, no other changes were made):

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "aks" {
  name                       = var.diag_name
  target_resource_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_workspace.id

  # Change 1 to disable "kube-audit"
  log {
    category       = "kube-audit"
    enabled        = false
  }

  # Change 2 to disable "kube-audit-admin"
  log {
    category       = "kube-audit-admin"
    enabled        = false
  }

  dynamic "log" {
    for_each = local.diag_agw_logs
    content {
      category = log.value

      retention_policy {
        days    = var.cluster_log_metrics_retention_in_days
        enabled = var.cluster_monitor_event_retention
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "metric" {
    for_each = local.diag_agw_metrics
    content {
      category = metric.value

      retention_policy {
        days    = var.cluster_log_metrics_retention_in_days
        enabled = var.cluster_monitor_event_retention
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what the resource JSON looks like after applying:

```
>> az monitor diagnostic-settings list --resource $(az aks list --query '[?contains(@.name, `mycluster`)].id | [0]' | tr -d '"')
[
  {
    "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": null,
    "eventHubName": null,
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/myresourcegroup/providers/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters/mycluster/providers/microsoft.insights/diagnosticSettings/mydiagnosticsetting",
    "identity": null,
    "kind": null,
    "location": null,
    "logAnalyticsDestinationType": null,
    "logs": [
      {
        "category": "cluster-autoscaler",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-scheduler",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-audit",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-audit-admin",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-controller-manager",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "guard",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-audit",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": false,
        "retentionPolicy": null
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-audit-admin",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": false,
        "retentionPolicy": null
      },
      {
        "category": "kube-apiserver",
        "categoryGroup": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "marketplacePartnerId": null,
    "metrics": [
      {
        "category": "AllMetrics",
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 7,
          "enabled": true
        },
        "timeGrain": null
      }
    ],
    "name": "mydiagnosticsetting",
    "resourceGroup": "myresourcegroup",
    "serviceBusRuleId": null,
    "storageAccountId": null,
    "systemData": null,
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
    "workspaceId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/myloganalyticsworkspace"
  }
]
```

As you can see, the "kube_audit" and "kube_audit_admin" log settings seem to both be enabled and disabled. What is the correct way to disable these settings via Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself so instead of deleting the question I decided to post it here. The problem was that the `dynamic "log"` resource kept overwriting the individual `log` blocks.

```
  dynamic "log" {
    for_each = local.diag_agw_logs. # <--- This was iterating over a list 
                                    #      with all the log settings, no 
                                    #      individual block needed
    content {
      category = log.value

      retention_policy {
        days    = var.cluster_log_metrics_retention_in_days
        enabled = var.cluster_monitor_event_retention
      }
    }
  }
```

So all that has to be done is deleting the `log` blocks that were already inserted to restore the original state of the resource `azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.aks`. Then modify the list the `dynamic` block is iterating over and everything works as expected.